# extracting a substring from a huge string

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a huge string. I need to extract a substring from that that huge string. The conditions are the string starts with either "TECHNICAL" or "JUSTIFY" and ends with a number, any number from 1 to 10. so for example, i have

string x = "This is a test, again I am test TECHNICAL: I need to extract this substring starting with testing. 8. This is test again and again and again and again";

so I need this

TECHNICAL: I need to extract this substring starting with testing.

I was wondering if someone has elegant solution for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression for that.
Example:

```
string input = "This is a test, again I am test TECHNICAL: I need to extract this substring starting with testing. 8. This is test again and again and again and again";
string pattern = @"(TECHNICAL|JUSTIFY).*?(10|[1-9])";

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex myTextRegex = new Regex(pattern);

Match match = myTextRegex.Match(input );
string matched = null;
if (match.Groups.Count > 0)
{
   matched = match.Groups[0].Value;
}

//Result: matched = TECHNICAL: I need to extract this substring starting with testing. 8
```

Comment: I'd use this regex: `(TECHNICAL|JUSTIFY).*?([1-9]|10)`.

Comment: I slightly changed the string and I am getting the wrong result. My new string is string input = "1.TECHNICAL: THIS is a test BLAH BLAH BLAH RAL ESTATE. 6. DESCRIPTION of the test". when i apply your regex, i only get 1 instead of TECHNICAL: This is a test BLAH BLAH BLAH REAL ESTATE.

Comment: @MRAB yes thanks that is simpler, I used yours but only make the `10` first so `(TECHNICAL|JUSTIFY).*?(10|[1-9])`

Comment: I updated the pattern like @MRAB suggested, now it should work fine ;)

Comment: @Anjali5: Group 0 captures the entire match, group 1 captures "TECHNICAL" or "JUSTIFY", group 2 captures the number at the end.

Comment: Is it possible to remove 8 from the string so I just need "TECHNICAL: I need to extract this substring starting with testing." instead of "TECHNICAL: I need to extract this substring starting with testing. 8."

Comment: Yes, use the following as a pattern and get `Group[1]` instead of [0] `@"((TECHNICAL|JUSTIFY).*?)(10|[1-9])"`

Comment: Thanks Jalal Aldeen Saa'd!! I have been struggling with this problem since morning.

Comment: You are welcome ;) don't forget to mark this answer as the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it answers you question right, so others will know if helps you